# System.Web.HttpContextWrapper2 error in sutekishop - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently try to use the [sutekishop .Net CMS product](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/) but am getting the error 
"Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextWrapper2'..."
Is this an MVC assembly mismatch? i have uninstalled mvc 5 and installed 3 (required according to the set up) but am still getting the issues.
Any ideas?

Rhys

Full error:

Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextWrapper2' from assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextWrapper2' from assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +0
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +36
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently upgraded to .NET 3.5 SP1? We did, and it caused this exact error message on our MVC website (we were using MVC Preview 2).

After uninstalling .NET 3.5 SP1, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks , but i have (possibly foolishy) attempted to port the whole thing to MVC 5. Being an ASP.net MVC noob this could get very interesting... 
At this stage the project builds but the tests dont. I really wish there was some decent documentation or at least a breaking changes document to go by. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I have upgraded. As this is not mission critical stuff, its for my GF's upstart business, so I have decided I want the latest, so i WANT to port this to MVC 5, i am not interested in going backwards. I guess i will have to suffer if this is the path i take. Cheers anyway.